# Typoscript HMENU special get available pages only

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

How to make this HMENU display only the available pages?

Hope it is clear: at the moment it displays links for pages that lead to a 404 - Page not found

```
20 = HMENU
20 {
    special = language
    special.value = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
    special.normalWhenNoLanguage = 0

    1 = TMENU
    1 {

        wrap (
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                        |
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )

        NO = 1
        NO {
            
            doNotLinkIt = 1
            linkWrap = |
            stdWrap {
          
                typolink {
                    parameter.data = page:uid
                    additionalParams = &L=0 || &L=1 || &L=3 || &L=4 || &L=5 || &L=6 || &L=7 || &L=8 || &L=9 
                    ATagParams = class="dropdown-item"
                    
                    addQueryString = 1
                    addQueryString.exclude = L,id,no_cache
                    addQueryString.method = GET
                    no_cache = 0
                }
            }

        }

        ACT < .NO
        ACT {
            stdWrap {
                typolink {
                    #Add class to disable already active language from dropdown items
                    ATagParams = class="disable-link-content"
                }
            }

        }

        USERDEF1 < .NO
        USERDEF1 {
            noLink = 1
        }

        USERDEF2 < .ACT
        USERDEF2 {
            noLink = 1
        }

    }

    #2 < .1

    #3 < .2

}
```

If more information is required please let me know..

Comment: Maybe you should try to implement it with the [MenuProcessor](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/LanguageMenuProcessor.html). It is more flexible, easy to implement and better to debug.

Comment: Thanks solved with the LanguageMenuProcessor

Answer (score 1):

there is no `noLink` option (although the manual of TYPO3 9 does include it in an example, which gets removed now)

use `doNotLinkIt = 1`

oh. as you already use it and generate the link on your own with `stdWrap.typoLink` you need to remove this link generation.